# Continuous Integration with Hudson and Automated Testing QWidgets

Tags: c++, unit-testing, qt, hudson, qwidget

I was playing around with Hudson on my development computer and ran into an issue where one of my automated unit tests has to create a QApplication in order to test a subclass of QWidget. Since hudson is running without X, this fails. The error log reads `unknown: cannot connect to X server`.

Is there a way for me to perform these tests automated using Hudson or a similar CI system? The library I'm using prevents me from separating this code under test from the QWidget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try launching some X server. Remember that it doesn't have to physically display anything--a VNC server will be enough. Then, set $DISPLAY environment variable in your hudson instance to point to the VNC server.

Comment: While I ended up splitting the code so that I could test the meat of it without the slow down involved in creating a QApplication and QWidgets, I also found the Xvnc plugin for Hudson which does exactly what this suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Unless they have the facilities required by the unit test, them passing or not is not useful information.  What are you really testing at that point?

- Conditionally compile the unit tests to not include them.  If you had Mac specific code, you wouldn't test it on Windows.

or

- Fix the unit tests